# Issues trying to download and install ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, tty

I tried to download the iso file for Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. But when I tried to install I got `invalid parameter error`. So a friend loaned me his Ubuntu 8.0 disk and I got the following error on that:

```
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off.
```

I am running an HP h8-1214 computer with an AMDfx 6160 six core 3300mhz processor and windows 7 home. Can anyone tell me how I can get Ubuntu onto my computer please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a bootable dvd/usb correctly? Assuming you're using Windows for this, these links have directions:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows
- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

And just in case you're using a EFI/UEFI computer: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Here's a nice official Ubuntu guide (with pictures!) to installing Ubuntu:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

The borrowed Ubuntu dvd of Ubuntu 8 is about 7 years old now, not supported and not recommended today.

Comment: I finally got 14.04 to install, but when I boot I get no root file directory, and I can't get into the partition menu